# how to clear my call when it is Truncated?

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, oledb, truncated

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal.OleDbConnectionInternal(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionString,
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection)
>     System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, object,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnection)
>     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, object,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnection,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
>     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolGroup,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
>     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection,
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal, out
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal)
>     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(System.Data.Common.DbConnection,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory,
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
>     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory,
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
>     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory)
>     System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
>     System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(System.Data.DataSet,
>   System.Data.DataTable[], int, int, string, System.Data.IDbCommand,
>   System.Data.CommandBehavior)
>       ...
>       [Call Stack Truncated]

**it shows up in my screen when i am testing a new app. there's similiar project, but only this one which always show this whenever i am testing some function.**

Can anyone help me? I am an amateur in this field. I am using latest Visual Studio.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsWD7.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you provide some details(code files) about how this happens?

Comment: It looks like an error when connecting to your data source but it's impossible for us to tell when we have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: I am trying to add "Search" Function to this app.
and it will automatically search as we type some letter in textbox.

But, if my database only have "GR or KP or TI or WK"
when i type GRK or KPT, that notice will show up as error
 notice.

Comment: Based on your picture, I find that your code is vb.net code instead of c# code. First, I suggest that you could add the vb.net tag. Second, I recommend that you provided a code example here.